# How do i click on a link that loads a html page and then using ajax (without clicking anything) load an external html page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

Hi i want to click on a button that loads a different html page and then i want to automatically load via ajax an external html page. How do i do that? Thanks

UPDATE

{
//link icon to correspoding link on what we do
$('#websites').click(function() {
$('#loading_content').hide().load('what-we-do/istoselides.html').fadeIn(1000)
return false;
});
}

That doesnt work cause of the return false. But it doesnt work neither when i take it away! Any ideas?? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: What do you mean by *external*? One that is not part of your domain?

Comment: i mean that it loads with ajax. its part of my site! i want with one click to load another html page and then via ajax another html page in that page!!

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to get you right. So you got a _page1.html_ with a link to _page2.html_ and when _page2.html_ is loading you want to load inside it with AJAX the content of _page3.html_ (nevermind the filename). Is that right ?

Comment: Could you provide a test page on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com)?

Comment: @Nyuszka7H : How do you want him to make this an example w/o doing a cross-domain ajax call ? :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8GAAh/ this is the test page. Shikiryu thats exactly what i want to do :D. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`.load()`**](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for this.